# Internet connection doesn't exist

Tags: networking, usb, internet

I'm not familiar with Ubuntu at all, however, today I received a USB with Ubuntu installed on it from my employer that I should be working on.
The problem is that, despite having my PC connected to an ethernet cable, the internet connection is just nonexistent when I boot up the Ubuntu from the USB.

I had tried using said USB on a PC and laptop from another family member and the internet works just fine as long as an ethernet cable is attached.
Therefore, I thought something must be wrong with my PC and I stupidly reset it (which naturally yielded no positive outcome). All I got from the IT department was advice to reset my router or try a different USB port.

Due to the fact that my access to the OS is most likely limited by my employer, I can't even look at my network settings or do any research/basic troubleshooting while using the booted up Ubuntu (even when I tried taking a look at the network settings on the other PC where I managed to connect to the internet, nothing appeared).
I'm unable to look at any settings overall, just basic things like accessibility.

In the "About" of the OS the following version of Ubuntu is shown: "Ubuntu 18.04.2 2021.11.16 customized using Cubic on 2021-11-16 10:25"

I hope someone is able to tell me if there is a possibility to work around this and what could maybe be the cause of the internet connection not being recognized.

Thanks!

Comment: Does your employer require you to use a specific VPN/tunnel?

Comment: @barrycarter Nope, I previously had a VPN on my PC that I uninstalled with the rest of my stuff since I thought that may be affecting it but when I think about it now, that could not have been the case since I have to start the USB OS in my boot menu

Comment: Basic troubleshooting: `sudo ifconfig -a`, have someone else log into your router and see if your machine known to the router. If you know your router's internal IP address, try `ping`ing it. Use `traceroute` and `mtr` to see what's going wrong. Use numerical IPs just in case it's DNS

Comment: @barrycarter I had tried what you suggested but the terminal refused to carry anything out. For sudo ifconfig -a, it tells me the command couldn't be found no matter how I write it, when pinging my IP address it says the network is unreachable, and trying a command like traceroute prompts me to install it, yet doesn't really carry the installation out. Here's an image of a block of code I encountered (https://imgur.com/a/6FyQhlI) - apologies for the picture as I had no other way to take it.

Comment: Please do not upload images of text. It is difficult to read and impossible to work with. Photos of your screen with text is even worse than a screenshot- a cardinal sin. Instead, edit your question and copy paste.  Use [code fences](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) on the line before and the line after the paste to preserve formatting. If you can't figure out the formatting, just copy paste and let us fix it for you.

Comment: As far as your question, you indicated that the same exact Ubuntu installation is able to perform the desired behavior on a different computer. This essentially rules out anything on that installation as the cause of the problem. If the problem is not unique to your Ubuntu installation, then it would apply that you probably can't fix this problem on Ubuntu. If the only variable is that it works on a different PC, I suggest trying to determine what is different about that PC from the other.  My guess is that it's a network configuration issue.

Comment: This ^^^ And almost all Ethernet devices are properly supported by the kernel (WiFi not so much), unless that's something so new that wasn't added yet. Are you perhaps booting the Ubuntu USB without properly shutting down Windows?

Comment: Does the command `sudo lshw -class network` work for you, and does it list any network interfaces? By the way, you would need the `net-tools` package for the `ifconfig` command, but of course, you can not install packages w/o internet access. However, you may be able to download this package from [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/net-tools/download) on an other computer, save it onto a separate USB, and then install it on the affected computer using `sudo dpkg -i net-tools_*.deb`).